# catkin_make fails: /opt/ros/kinetic/include/std_msgs/Float32.h errors

Tags: ros, catkin-make, std-msgs, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed ROS Kinetic from source on Debian 9 running on the BeagleBone Blue. I can run roscore and successfully create a workspace. I'm trying to create a node/package that will control the motors of a rover. I'm using the Float32 message type in my code. after sourcing the setup.bash for both my kinetic install and workspace, I run catkin_make from the root of the workspace. The following output is printed:

```
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 33%] Building CXX object drive/CMakeFiles/drive.dir/src/drive.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/string:40,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/std_msgs/Float32.h:9,
                 from /home/rover/RoverDaemons/src/drive/src/drive.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:243:56: error: macro "min" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
     min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare __comp)
                                                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:60:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/algorithm:62,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/tools/config.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:13,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/time.h:58,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/serialization.h:34,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/std_msgs/Float32.h:14,
                 from /home/rover/RoverDaemons/src/drive/src/drive.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/algorithmfwd.h:375:41: error: macro "min" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
     min(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, _Compare);
                                         ^
```

The output I've included is abbreviate to include only the first 2 errors but there are many more all referencing the Float32.h file. The drive.cpp code looks like

```
/* drive_node.cpp
 * licence: GPLv3
 */

#include "MotorControl.hpp"
#include <rc_usefulincludes.h> 
#include <roboticscape.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace rover;

void speedCallback(const std_msgs::Float32::ConstPtr& msg, 
        MotorControl motor_control){
    /* if they differ from current values then set speed and diff to new */
    if( msg->data != motor_control.get_speed() ){
        motor_control.set_speed(msg->data);
    }

    /* publish new speed to /drive_status */

}

void diffCallback(const std_msgs::Float32::ConstPtr& msg,
        MotorControl motor_control){
    /* if they differ from current values then set speed and diff to new */
    if( msg->data != motor_control.get_diff() ){
        motor_control.set_diff(msg->data);
    }

    /* publish new diff to /drive_status */

}

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

    MotorControl motor_control = new MotorControl();

    ros::init(argc, argv, "drive");
        
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    /* subscribe to /drive_speed and /drive_diff */
    ros::Subscriber speedSub = n.subscribe("drive_speed", 1000, 
        boost::bind(speedCallback, _1, motor_control));
    ros::Subscriber diffSub = n.subscribe("diff_speed", 1000, 
        boost::bind(diffCallback, _1, motor_control));

    ros::spin();

        // exit cleanly
    delete(motor_control);

        return 0;
}
```

I thought it might be an issue with the C++ version I'm using to build the node but I had no luck adding "add_compile_options(-std=c++03)" to src/drive/CMakeLists.txt. The contents of the CMakeLists.txt is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(drive)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(drive src/drive.cpp src/MotorControl.cpp)
add_dependencies(drive ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

target_link_libraries(drive roboticscape ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

 install(TARGETS drive drive
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
 )
```

Does anyone have any clues as to why I can't build my node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283177/catkin_make-fails:-/opt/ros/kinetic/include/std_msgs/float32.h-errors/) by [omgrobots](https://answers.ros.org/users/33770/omgrobots/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like [rc_usefulincludes.h](https://github.com/StrawsonDesign/Robotics_Cape_Installer/blob/1dfcf302a5f76e68dc005673d411002181b73ce9/libraries/rc_usefulincludes.h#L58) redefines the `min` macro, and this is incompatible with `std::min` that is defined by the C++ standard library: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/ . When other STL libraries try to call the standard 3-argument version of `min`, they fail. (This is valid even for C++98, so switching C++ versions will result in the same incompatibility)

You should probably either file a bug about this with that library, or fix it yourself by removing that line from that header, and updating the library to use `std::min` instead.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omgrobots](https://answers.ros.org/users/33770/omgrobots/) on 2018-02-19**:
Yes! I can't believe I missed that. I removed the reference to rc_usefulincludes.h and the errors disappeared. I will follow up with the authors of that file. Thanks!